# Dynamic length variable with argument? (like "\setlength{\foo}[1]{0.5+#1*0.5}")

Tags: macros, lengths

**Is there a way to define some kind of a length function that takes an argument, sort of a mixture between `\newcommand` and `\setlength`?**

The following example should illustrate what I want. *(I'm using a tikz tree because that's where I've encountered this problem, but the way I see it the question is not tikz-specific.)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\unit}
\setlength{\unit}{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {hello}
    child{ 
        node[yshift=-0.5\unit-5*0.5\unit] {world}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code I'd like to put in a variable is `-0.5\unit-5*0.5\unit`. I'd like to replace it by something like `\foo{5}`, that could be defined as `\setlength{\foo}[1]{-0.5\unit-#1*0.5\unit}` (that's what it might look like if `\setlength` could process arguments that same way as `\newcommand`).

`\newcommand` doesn't work because it defines a command, not a length, and `\setlength` doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want some thing like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\unit}
\setlength{\unit}{2cm}
\newcommand\foo[1]{-0.5\unit-#1\unit}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {hello}
    child{ 
        node[yshift=\foo{2.5}] {world}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

here 2.5=5*0.5

Comment: Yes! But I could swear this failed when I tried it.. Must've had a typo somewhere.